# Differential equations and motion

Tags: calculus

*A population of insects increases at a rate of $160 + 6 t +0.3 t^2$ insects per day. Find the insect population after $3$ days, assuming that there are $40$ insects at $t=0$.*

I took the antideriv and then added $40$ (the C) and got $549.7$, which is incorrect.

Comment: I get the same answer as you. Any clue what the "correct" answer is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you go with $P(3)=P(0)+\int_0^3{160+6t+0.3t^2}dt$ as suggested by ah-huh-moment and as you have already done. But since you are *counting* insects, you should round it to the nearest whole number: 550.

However, the wording of the question could suggest that you should calculate the number of new insects each day (not using calculus). Doing so produces:

- End of day 1: $40+160+6+0.3 = 206.3$
- End of day 2: $206.3+160+12+1.2 = 379.5$
- End of day 3: $379.5+160+18+2.7=560.2$

Rounded to produce 560 insects. Rounding of each intermediate step still produces the same rounded result.

Answer (score 0):

Use: $P(3) = P(0) + \displaystyle \int_{0}^3 (160+6t+0.3t^2)dt$

Comment: I get $P(3)=549.7$ from this (via Wolfram Alpha), same as the OP.